# Grails OAuth provider 404 on /token

Tags: grails, groovy, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

Hi I am trying to setup an OAuth provider using this documentation from grails: [Grails Documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/latest/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html)

I have done all the steps but when I try to do a request in postman I always got a 404 not found. I have tried many configs and I also tried some different `filterChain.chainMap`

I also have a MobileController that works fine that I can access in the project. I have tried to copy and paste the filterchain filters to make it the same as on /mobile/ But it still gave me a 404, I have ran the init script (s2-init-oauth2-provider) to make the domain classes

Here is my code that matters for the OAuth provider:

grails-app/conf/application.groovy:

```
List<String> url_public = [
        '/mobile/**',
        '/oauth/token'
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        [pattern: '/oauth/token', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter'],
        [pattern: '/mobile/**',   filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS, -securityContextPersistenceFilter, -logoutFilter, -authenticationProcessingFilter, -rememberMeAuthenticationFilter, -oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter, -exceptionTranslationFilter'],
        [pattern: '/**',          filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS, -basicAuthenticationFilter, -basicExceptionTranslationFilter, -statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter, -oauth2ProviderFilter, -clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter, -oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter, -oauth2ExceptionTranslationFilter'],
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.clientLookup.className = 'com.app.oauth.OAuthClient'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.authorizationCodeLookup.className = 'com.app.oauth.AuthorizationCode'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.accessTokenLookup.className = 'com.app.oauth.AccessToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.refreshTokenLookup.className = 'com.app.oauth.RefreshToken'
```

grails-app/init/Bootstrap.groovy:

```
new OAuthClient(
                clientId: 'client_id',
                authorizedGrantTypes: ['authorization_code', 'refresh_token', 'implicit', 'password', 'client_credentials'],
                authorities: ['ROLE_client'],
                scopes: ['read', 'write'],
        ).save(flush: true)

        println "End bootstrap.init "
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix was that I had to remove the url from the url_public list.

```
List<String> url_public = [
        '/mobile/**'
]
```